# ASTC Texture compression in metal– what should I use as the bytes per row?

Tags: swift, textures, metal

I'm writing a program that's using compressed textures in Metal. I'm having a bit of trouble with the `replaceRegion()` function of MTLTexture. The parameter `bytesPerRow` just doesn't seem to make sense. It says that for compressed textures, "`bytesPerRow` is the number of bytes from the beginning of one row of blocks to the beginning of the next."

Now I'm using ASTC with 4x4 blocks, which means that I have 8 bpp. So then 4*4 is 16, and 8 bits is one byte. So I'm guessing that each block size is 16 bytes. But yet, when I enter 16, I get a failed assertion that requires the minimum value to be 4096. What's going on?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your error message suggests that the minimum x dimension for an ASTC texture (at least with 4x4 block footprint) is 1024. I don't always want something that big!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bytesPerRow = texelsPerRow / blockFootprint.x * 16

Comment: Thank you so much. Just a question: why do I multiply it by 16? Is it because there are 16 pixels per block?

Comment: Every ASTC block consists of 16 bytes (128 bits), regardless of how many texels it represents in 2D or 3D.

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
uint32_t bytes_per_row(uint32_t texture_width, uint32_t block_width) {
  return (texture_width % block_width ? texture_width + (texture_width % block_width) : texture_width) / block_width * 16;
}
```

This rounds up the texture width to a multiple of the block width first. E.g. a 1024x1024 texture encoded with a block size of 6x6 corresponds to 2736 bytes per row.  1026 / 6 * 16 == 2736.